# Building a "This Week" & "Next Week" Link Query

Tags: php, date, calendar

I'm building a script for an events website and I have shortcut links for "Today, 7 Days, 14 Days, 30 Days & 60 Days, using PHP to get each day count from today which works fine but I'd prefer to have it as "Today, This Week, Next Week" and then let the users do a custom search for anything further in the future. Problem is I have no idea how to get the weeks for this type of calculation. For example I could do this week as "From today to +7" and then do next week as "Today +7 to Today +14" but this would be a bit confusing, so what I want to do is:

```
Today = Today //I have the script for this
This Week = Today (Whichever day we are on) to Sunday
Next Week = Next Monday to Next Sunday
```

Any Ideas how this is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo $today = date("d/m/Y");
echo "<br>";
echo $thisweekends = date("d/m/Y",strtotime("next sunday")); 
echo "<br>";
echo $nextweekstarts = date("d/m/Y",strtotime("next monday"));
echo "<br>";
echo $nextweekends = date("d/m/Y",strtotime("+7 days",strtotime("next sunday")));
```

Comment: Thanks, this works brilliantly and I can see how the strtotime() function can be useful for other features. I've now added a link to filter out the weekend using ("this friday"). Great answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
date_default_timezone_set(GMT);
$date = date("d/m/Y");// current date
$date = strtotime(date("d/m/Y", strtotime($date)) . " +1 week");

$year = date("Y",$date);
$week = date("W",$date);
echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($year . 'W' . str_pad($week, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)));
```

returns 16/09/2013

if you change +1 week to +2 it
returns 23/09/2013

Comment: Yes but this wouldn't get an accurate Monday to Sunday week which is what I want would it?

Comment: Thanks, This does work but it's a little bit long winded for what I want to do for other date customisations.

Comment: You're welcome. The code can be trimmed down a lot, but for ease of learning I broke it up so you people can more clearly see what is going on and adapt it for their own use.